# postsharp is failing to work on .net core

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, aop, postsharp

I am trying to use postsharp on .net core 2.

I have added Postsharp 5.1.19 (preview) however, I am getting the following error when I try to build the project.

> /Users/me/.nuget/packages/postsharp/5.1.9-preview/build/PostSharp.targets(5,5): Error MSB4060: The "PostSharp30" task has been declared or used incorrectly, or failed during construction. Check the spelling of the task name and the assembly name. (MSB4060) `

Here is a detailed explanation which is essentially not aware that I am on MAC and still looking for (kernel32) and some dlls:

> /Users/me/.nuget/packages/postsharp/5.1.9-preview/build/PostSharp.targets(5,5): Error MSB4061: The "PostSharp30" task could not be instantiated from "/Users/me/.nuget/packages/postsharp/5.1.9-preview/build/PostSharp.MSBuild.v5.1.9.Release.dll". 
>   System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'PostSharp.Compiler.Client.BuildClient' threw an exception. ---> System.DllNotFoundException: kernel32
>     at (wrapper managed-to-native) PostSharp.Compiler.Client.ProcessUtilities.GetCurrentProcess()
>     at PostSharp.Compiler.Client.ProcessUtilities.GetParentProcesses () [0x00006] in <7cce0190f299453c822c4cfb425f86da>:0 
>     at PostSharp.Compiler.Client.ProcessUtilities.DetectUnattendedProcess (System.String& log) [0x0002f] in <7cce0190f299453c822c4cfb425f86da>:0 
>     at PostSharp.Compiler.Client.BuildClient..cctor () [0x00016] in <7cce0190f299453c822c4cfb425f86da>:0 
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>     at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Object.__icall_wrapper_mono_generic_class_init(intptr)
>     at PostSharp.MSBuild.PostSharp30..ctor () [0x00018] in <7cce0190f299453c822c4cfb425f86da>:0 
>     at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.InternalInvoke(System.Reflection.MonoCMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
>     at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.InternalInvoke (System.Object obj, System.Object[] parameters) [0x00002] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5533/mono-mac-sdk/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:661  (MSB4061)`

How can I get this working?

Answer (score 2):

As you can read in the [announcement](http://www.postsharp.net/blog/post/Announcing-PostSharp-51-Preview-Support-for-NET-Standard-20-and-NET-Core-20):

> PostSharp 5.1 will still only support Windows as the only build
>   platform.

So even though .NET Core projects are supported, you can build with PostSharp only on Windows, and as you said - you are on MAC.

Comment: I see. I have seen that page, but didnt pay attention to that line. Thanks.